# Organization Browser in SharePoint 2010

Tags: organization-browser

Is there an object model solution that can be used to create an organization chart in SharePoint 2010
similar to the built-in web part in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API and Web Services support pulling colleagues and the user's supervisor.  There are a number ways you can create an org chart from that, but there is no way I've seen to export the complete hierarchical structure.